# Vim: Soft wrap and long lines with at-signs

Tags: vim, at-sign

I have a buffer with `:set wrap` enabled. It appears like this:

[image: Long line replaced with @ signs]

If I make the window just a little bigger, the `@` signs in the gutter go away, and I can see the full line.

[image: Long line without @ signs]

My question is what option governs these `@` at-signs, and how can I change vim to show me these long lines when I can't see the end of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the `@` symbols, enable the `lastline` flag in the [`'display'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'display') option, for example by putting the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
set display=lastline
```

The [`window-contents`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#window-contents) section of the vim manual describes the resulting behavior in more detail, but briefly, this will truncate the end of the last line and replace it with `@@@` (to indicate that it is cut off by the bottom edge of the window), instead of hiding the entire last line behind at signs.